# matching data after a dash using substring or charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation in which I have to match user input data to the data in msql data table

lets say user input is `123` and database value is `1111-123` or `15454454aa-4545`. So I have to match the data after left side dash.

Here is my query but I am unable to get it.

```
select left(column1,LEN(column1)-CHARINDEX('-',column1)) 
from table where column1='123'
```

Comment: lets say user input is 123 and database value is 1111-123 or 15454454aa-4545  ,,specfying output simplifies question  a lot

Comment: you can use your select statement in where clause as it is `WHERE left(column1,LEN(column1)-CHARINDEX('-',column1)) ='123'`

Comment: If the left and right sides of the dash have a special meaning consider storing them in separate columns.  You could also add a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that joins them back together.  You approach makes all values immediately available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to cut what you need from `column1`:

```
select * 
from YourTable 
where SUBSTRING(column1,CHARINDEX('-',column1)+1,LEN(column1)) ='123'
```

Or [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx):

```
select *
from YourTable 
where PARSENAME(REPLACE(column1,'-','.'),1) ='123'
```

Or [RIGHT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx):

```
select *
from YourTable 
where RIGHT(column1,LEN(column1)-CHARINDEX('-',column1)) ='123'
```

Or [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
select *
from YourTable 
where STUFF(column1,1,CHARINDEX('-',column1),'')='123'
```

Or [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
select *
from YourTable 
where column1 LIKE '%-'+'123'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING(column1, CHARINDEX('-',column1) +1, LEN(column1) - CHARINDEX('-',column1))
```

Comment: Hi Jan - your code-only answer would be better with some added context. For example, you could explain how and why this code will work to solve the questioner's specific problem; it would then be more useful also to other readers searching for help with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select 
  left(column1,LEN(column1)-CHARINDEX('-',column1))
  --the items in the select portion aren't important for 
  --finding a match, this part can be anything, column name, * etc.      
  from table where column1 LIKE '%-' + '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the search string can be ANYWHERE after the dash

```
Declare @YourTable table (column1 varchar(150))
Insert into @YourTable values
('1111-123'),
('1111-###123###'),
('15454454aa-4545')

Declare @Search varchar(50) = '123'

Select * from @YourTable 
 Where column1 like '%-%'+@Search+'%'
```

Returns

```
column1
1111-123
1111-###123###
```